# how to set object param directly when page load with javascript?

Tags: javascript

i want to read directly from params values to NPAPi plugin

here is my current JS and form code

```
<script>
var control = document.getElementById('embed');
</script>


<form name="formname">
<input type=button value="Inc name" onclick='embed.name="albert";'>
<input type=button value="Inc phone" onclick='embed.phone="123456";'>

</form>
```

This is work fine to pass `embed.name` and `embed.phone` to my dll

how to set params directly with javascript in same way without using form or on click event like this :

```
<EMBED id="embed" TYPE="application/x-plugin" ALIGN=CENTER WIDTH=400 HEIGHT=300>
<param name="name" value="albert" />   
<param name="phone" value="123456" /> 
</EMBED>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use setAttribute to create name value pairs.

```
document.getElementById("embed").setAttribute("name", "albert");
document.getElementById("embed").setAttribute("phone", "123456");
```

Then you can access the values with getAttribute later, although I am not sure if "embed" is a reserved word for an element id.

Comment: Right, you can read them after you set them.

After you set: 
document.getElementById("embed").setAttribute("phone", "123456");

You can read them like this:

var myParam = document.getElementById("embed").getAttribute("phone");

Comment: result null i just test it :( `alert(myParam);` also another point i want to set this  property like this for each param , `embed.<param name> = <param value >;`

Comment: example to show what i mean  `cdefine = document.getElementById("myParam").name;
rdefine = document.getElementById("myParam").value;
embed.cdefine = rdefine;
alert(embed.cdefine);`

Comment: I see what you are trying to do now.

Here: 

document.getElementById("myDiv").name ="Bob";
document.getElementById("myDiv").age ="32";
document.getElementById("myDiv").pet ="cat";

You can now simply refer to each "property" of this element like so:

alert(document.getElementById("myDiv").name);

Comment: but i have to repeat the lines can i use foreach param id read its value ?

Comment: also i treid and didnt work `var control = document.getElementById('embed');
function myFunction() {
x = document.getElementById("myParam").name;
control.x=document.getElementById("myParam").value;
}
myFunction();`